# Encoding the entire location.href string

Tags: javascript, url, encoding

I am redirecting the user using `window.location.href`.

If I do not switch the `&` to `&amp;` joining the URL parameters in the string, IE7 and IE8 complain (for example, the `&reg` is turned into a registered trademark symbol).

If I just write the `&` as `&amp;`, my modern Firefox 24.0 doesn't process the parameters because it just reads them as straight `&amp;`.

How can I encode the URL in such a way that makes both browsers happy? [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) just breaks the whole thing for everyone.

```
window.location.href = '/ex/mypage.php?MemberID=' + memberID + '&reg=reg&rid=' + return_data + '&YearRegisteringFor=' + regYear;
```

Comment: Just a guess:  Try using `window.location` instead

Comment: @lzkata Just tried it, it did not make a difference.

Comment: Did you try to post a URI rather than just the path? (i.e. http://example.com/ex/mypage.php?...)

Comment: I would just forfeit and use a different url parameter name. This is a known bug in IE7/8, and the only fix is to use `&amp;` in place of `&`, which as you can see, makes it stop working correctly in firefox 24.0. You could use browser detection, or possibly find a way to detect support for using `&reg=`, however that's far more maintenance heavy than just changing the parameter name.

Comment: @Sebastian That wouldn't make a difference in this case

Comment: @KevinB Although giving up isn't always the answer, sometimes it is; can you make your comment an answer instead please?

Comment: @John I know it doesn't make a difference for the answer, but it makes a difference regarding finding the issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just forfeit and use a different url parameter name. This is a known bug in IE7/8, and the only fix is to use `&amp;` in place of `&`, which as you can see, makes it stop working correctly in firefox 24.0.

You could use browser detection, or possibly find a way to detect support for using `&reg=`, however that's far more maintenance heavy than just changing the parameter name.